# Drupal 7 unable to run web installer

Tags: drupal

B"H

Hi

I'm trying to install CiviCRM with a local Drupal 7 installation on windows 7, with XXAMP etc.

I have drupal 7 working fine, I downloaded the [source code for civicrm](https://civicrm.org/download) (file name `civicrm-5.35.1-drupal`), extraced it to `C:\xampp\htdocs\yidpool\sites\all\modules\civicrm` (yidpool is my drupal folder), then in the drupal modules section I see:

[image]

So as you can see it's all there except for the rules and the OG sync. OK fine, so I save it, then I go to `http://localhost:777/yidpool/civicrm/dashboard` after clicking on a link that appears on one of the blocks on the home screen, then I'm greeted with this page:

[image]

And I'm not able to do anything else, if I click on the "Confirguration..." it opens a new tab to the same exact page, and the standard install page that the docs said I should see don't appear.

Any idea how to procede?

Comment: After you checked the checkbox to enable the module and click save, did it give you `CiviCRM is almost ready. You must configure CiviCRM for it to work.` which includes a link to `/civicrm/setup`, which then gives you an installer page.

Comment: @demerit no I didn't get that message

Comment: Ok, I guess you could try going to /civicrm/setup and see if it will let you still do that. Otherwise I'd try again, uninstalling the module and removing sites/default/civicrm.settings.php. The message is easy to miss, since it's just regular text inside the green success box after enabling the module.

Comment: @demerit uninstalled xxampp as me reinstalled it in different folder, cleared cash, re installed drupal with be database etc, to now time I install l civicrm from modules, and selected the tar archive instead of just copying the folder, this time I got the message, but the link takes me to the same page as above which doesn't go anywhere, is it not compatible with windows 7?

Comment: Logout from drupal and login back

Comment: Civi is compatible with windows 7 but I don't remember if I tried this install method with it. You can also still use the regular installer, where you don't install the module on the modules page, you just unzip the tarball and visit /sites/all/modules/civicrm/install/index.php. You can also use `cv core:install` - see https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/general/cli-cv/

Comment: @pradeep did and same result